# Why is the DCM operation not relevant for the compensator design in a voltage-mode buck converter?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, control-system, transfer-function

I am trying to find out the type-3 compensator design for a buck converter in voltage mode which may operate in CCM as well as in DCM. In this [application note](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva301/slva301.pdf?ts=1675774537364&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) from TI on page 16 (bottom) it is stated that for compensator design only the CCM mode is considered.

[image]

Why is this a right way to design? Does the change in the transfer function from CCM to DCM not matter for the compensator network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A buck converter operated in voltage-mode control (VM), whether it is operated in continuous conduction mode (CCM) or discontinuous conduction mode (DCM), remains a second-order system. In CCM, the two poles incurred to the \$LC\$ network peak at the resonance and the phase very quickly hits -180° unless the zero brought by the capacitor ESR breaks the -2-slope into a -1-slope and makes the phase land at -90°.

In DCM, the two poles have split and the system is now heavily damped. One pole dominates at low frequency while the second is relegated to higher values. The state-space averaging (SSA) technique was not able to predict this behavior as it incorrectly flagged the DCM buck as a 1st-order system. It is Vatché Vorpérian who did demonstrate in 1986 with his PWM-switch model that the buck was still a second-order system but heavily damped in DCM. This observation remains valid for the two other switching cells, the buck-boost and the boost converter.

If during its nominal operation, the buck converter remains in DCM, it might be tempting to compensate only for a DCM ac response. However, a buck is, most of the time, designed for CCM operation to minimize core losses and will enter DCM in light-load conditions. Even if light-load is your permanent sweet operating point for any reason, at power up, until the loop stabilizes, CCM will be entered and the converter must be stable during this phase.

Below is a VM buck available as a ready-made [SIMPLIS template](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf) you can download from my [page](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Spice.htm). The right-side text window is an automated compensation macro which calculates the type 3 components values around the op-amp. The converter is compensated for a 5-kHz crossover, well beyond the resonant frequency:

[image]

The loop gain ac response for CCM confirms the 5-kHz crossover target with a 70° phase margin. If the converter now operates in DCM (50-ohm load), then the ac response drastically changes with a crossover collapsing to 200 Hz and a lower phase margin. This is the typical behavior of the buck operated in voltage-mode control and transitioning from one mode to the other. Actually, if you implement the k-factor (a double pole-zero pair placed before and after crossover) in CCM, you may potentially run into conditional stability in light load. The trick is to place one zero at the resonant frequency (500-600 Hz) and another one slightly below. This helps boosting the phase when the converter enters DCM and prevents conditional stability.

As a quick summary, always make sure the converter is compensated for CCM operation and check that DCM is run in a stable area. Mode transition is easier to deal with in current-mode control but you have to inject slope compensation.

If you want more information on the buck topology and its compensation, I invite you to take a look at my [APEC 2019](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202019.pdf) seminar dedicated to this topology.